# How to flip y axis in geom_sf()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

Trying to combine a `geom_sf()` with some other geoms. I need to reverse the y-axis for the plot to appear correctly. However, `geom_sf()` seems to ignore `scale_y_reverse()`.

Example:

```
# install the dev version of ggplot2
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

# make triangle
tmpdf <- data.frame(id = 1,
                    geom = c("LINESTRING(10 10,-10 10,0 0,10 10)"), stringsAsFactors = F)


# read WKT polygons into 'sp' SpatialPolygons object
tmpdf$spgeom <- lapply(tmpdf$geom, FUN = function(x) readWKT(x))

# extract coordinates from the linestring (there has got to be a better way to do this...)
test <- tmpdf[1,"spgeom"]
test2 <- sapply(test, FUN=function(x) x@lines)
test3 <- sapply(test2, FUN=function(x) x@Lines)
test4 <- lapply(test3, FUN=function(x) x@coords)

# plot the sp coordinates
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x,y), color="blue") + 
  geom_path(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x=x, y=y), color="blue") + 
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: ggplot sp geom only]

```
# make an 'sf' sfc_POLYGON object
tmpdf$sfgeom <- st_as_sfc(tmpdf$geom) 

## plot both together, they overlap
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x,y), color="blue") + 
  geom_path(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x=x, y=y), color="blue") + 
  coord_fixed() +  
  geom_sf(data=tmpdf, aes(geometry=sfgeom), color="red")
```

[image: ggplot both geoms]

plot outputs with warning:

> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which
>   will replace the existing one.

```
## plot with scale reverse, and everything but the geom_sf flips.
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x,y), color="blue") + 
  geom_path(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x=x, y=y), color="blue") + 
  coord_fixed() +  
  geom_sf(data=tmpdf, aes(geometry=sfgeom), color="red") + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image: ggplot y reversed]

plot outputs with warning:

> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which
>   will replace the existing one.

Suggestions for getting the geom_sf y coordinates reversed?

I tried this:

```
coord_sf(ylim=-(range(st_coordinates(tmpdf$sfgeom)[,"Y"])))
```

and all that did was change the axis, not the actual geoms.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like `geom_sf` can only take one kind of coordinates (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_sf_coordinates.html).  To me, this indicates that you can't flip it or reverse it (no Missy Elliot reference intended).

Comment: ha. so, i searched for st_* functions that would allow me to reverse the y coordinates.  probably need a coordinate setter. the following doesn't work: `st_coordinates(tmpdf$sfgeom)[,"Y"]  = st_coordinates(tmpdf$sfgeom)[,"Y"]*-1`

Comment: Off topic, but what's the point of this geom and why use it?

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html visualizing spatial features objects. e.g., from a spatial database, shapefile, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Here's a workaround:

```
## get the geom coordinates as data.frame
geomdf <- st_coordinates(tmpdf$sfgeom)

## reverse Y coords
geomdf[,"Y"] <- geomdf[,"Y"]*-1

## re-create geom
tmpdf$sfgeom2 <- st_as_sfc(st_as_text(st_linestring(geomdf)))

## plot the reversed y-coordinate geom:
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x,y), color="blue") + 
  geom_path(data=data.frame(test4[[1]]), aes(x=x, y=y), color="blue") + 
  coord_fixed() +  
  geom_sf(data=tmpdf, aes(geometry=sfgeom2), color="red") + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```